# Ionic 2: How to load scripts in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently playing around with ionic 2 using angular 2 and typescript. Now I am trying to write some scripts in a html page (or include it in the file).

I know, that javascript libraries should be included in the index.html file, located in the www root folder. But what if I want to insert a script in a single html page?

For example I need to have a floating cube on a page. I do the right thing by including the three.js (3D library) in the root html file, but including a floatingcube.js file in the page html file (or writing the script in the file), doesn't work.

I don't know if I made a mistake here, but maybe someone knows how to work with external libraries and how to write scripts in ionic 2.

**EDIT:** Here is the rotating cube JS part:

***JS:***

```
var camera;
var scene;
var renderer;
var mesh;
var geometry;
var material1;
var material2;
var material3;
var material4;
var material5;
var material6;
var materials;
var meshFaceMaterial;
var isMouseDown = false;



init();
animate();

function init() {

    window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart);
    window.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 25;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

  light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xE6E6E6 );
  scene.add( light );

    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10);
    material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/cub1.jpg') } );
    material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/cub2.jpg') } );
    material3 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/cub3.jpg') } );
    material4 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/cub4.jpg') } );
    material5 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/cub5.jpg') } );
    material6 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/cub6.jpg') } );

    materials = [material1, material3, material5, material6, material4, material2];

    meshFaceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, meshFaceMaterial );
    mesh.position.z = 0;
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.getElementById('render').appendChild( renderer.domElement );   
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    render();
}

function onMouseDown(){
    isMouseDown = true;
}

function onMouseUp(){
    isMouseDown = false;
}

function handleStart(){
    isMouseDown = true;
}

function handleEnd(){
    isMouseDown = false;
}

function animate() {
 if(!isMouseDown){
        mesh.rotation.x += .012;
        mesh.rotation.y += .014;
        mesh.rotation.z += .018;
    }
 else {
        mesh.rotation.x += .0;
        mesh.rotation.y += .0;
        mesh.rotation.y += .0;
 }
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    render();
}
```

Comment: Could you add part of that `floatingcube.js` file? Because I guess that the correct way to do it (thinking in an *angular 2 way* would be to create a custom directive for that floating cube, and add the related code inside that directive. I can help you with that if you want :)

Comment: Hi! I updated the post ;)